# android stackoverflow error on imagebutton clicked

Tags: android, stack-overflow

```
ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(et.getText()!=null){
                tosearch=et.getText().toString();
                    Intent seach=new Intent(getActivity(), Search.class);
                seach.putExtra("key", seach);
                startActivity(seach);
            }
        }
    });
```

My ImageButton click listener is above.and im getting follwing error

```
07-25 01:30:59.017: D/dalvikvm(1699): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 127K, 50% free   2843K/5575K, external 5307K/5765K, paused  
31ms 07-25 01:31:02.791: I/dalvikvm(1699): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/os/Parcel;.writeInt:VI
07-25 01:31:02.791: I/dalvikvm(1699):   method requires 8+20+0=28 bytes, fp is 0x4428a318 (24 left)
07-25 01:31:02.791: I/dalvikvm(1699):   expanding stack end (0x4428a300 to 0x4428a000)
07-25 01:31:02.791: I/dalvikvm(1699): Shrank stack (to 0x4428a300, curFrame is 0x4428cebc)
07-25 01:31:02.791: D/AndroidRuntime(1699): Shutting down VM
07-25 01:31:02.791: W/dalvikvm(1699): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
07-25 01:31:02.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 01:31:02.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1699): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-25 01:31:02.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1699):     at android.net.Uri.writeToParcel(Uri.java:1645)
07-25 01:31:02.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1699):     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5601)
07-25 01:31:02.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1699):     at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
```

My application consist of mainactivity with three fragments and second activity.I have searched but couldn't find anything helpfull. please help to solve the error .

Comment: putting an intent into itself as an extra is not going to serialize nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this line is the problem

```
 seach.putExtra("key", seach);
```

it looks like it should be

```
 seach.putExtra("key", tosearch);
```

You are putting the `Intent` inside itself as an `extra`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a recursive loop whe placing the `extra`. Remember an `extra` is defined as `Intent.putExtra("key", value);'

The `value` you are inputting is the `intent` itself. Which will get larger and larger.